# synctex.gz file is (busy)

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, texmaker

I'm trying to compile my LaTeX file (an article), but I keep getting a Windows API error: my synctex file is busy - the filename has been changed and appended with (busy).

I'm using TexMaker to compile the file, but it occurs in TeXStudio as well.

When I create a new file I can compile it once before this issue occurs.

The API error is

> pdflatex: Windows API error 4350:  This file is currently not available for use on this computer. pdflatex: Data: Report4.synctex.gz

Comment: There are no whitespaces in the title, and I installed MiKTeX a few days ago.

Comment: Can you check if the Task Manager still shows an instance of *TeX still running? (Kill it.)

Comment: That's not the issue: I've even re-installed MiKTeX and the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiling process has actually not yet or not properly ended. Therefore also the file ending `.gz(busy)` – when the compiling had ended properly, it would have been renamed to `.gz`. So the files are still marked as used for Windows, and a second compiler run will fail. From your information I cannot say anything about the reasons.