# How to avoid " busy synctex.gz file" all together

Tags: errors, compiling

I am running TeXShop 3.61 on Mac, I have read many similar questions (for example the post by Werner: [How do I close a busy synctex.gz file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168324/how-do-i-close-a-busy-synctex-gz-file))on this problem of "synctex.gz file" popping up when there is an error and I know deleting the file "xxx.synctex.gz(busy)" solves this problem. The trouble I have now is that whenever there is any mistake in my code (however small) when I hit compile, this problem shows up, and I have to go through (after correcting the mistake in my code) closing the document, deleting the relevant files, and reopen my document to keep on editing. My question is how do I avoid this problem from showing up entirely? I wish when the log tells me there is a mistake in my code, I could simply correct it and compile again.

Comment: How do you stop compilation when you have an error?

Comment: I actually don't know. Are you implying that the reason I cannot just change code and compile again is that the previous compilation has not stopped? So is there actually a simple way to stop it? @UlrikeFischer

Comment: I type x on my keyboard and then enter to close a compilation on an error. But I'm on windows, and I don't use nonstopmode or a hidden compilation or something like this.